# set containing a class with CString member variables stores only first letters

Tags: c++, stl, mfc, cstring

I am working with MFC and I have this class:

```
class CUnit
{
private:
    CString name;
    CString init;
    CString chp;
    CString rhp;
    CString condition;
public:
    CUnit(void);
    ~CUnit(void);
    void setName( CString str );
    void setInit( CString str );
    void setCHP( CString str );
    void setRHP( CString str );
    void setCond( CString str );
    CString getName() const;
    CString getInit() const;
    CString getCHP() const;
    CString getRHP() const;
    CString getCond() const;    
    bool operator< ( CUnit ) const;
};

CUnit::CUnit(void)
{
}


CUnit::~CUnit(void)
{
}

bool CUnit::operator< ( CUnit unit ) const
{
    return !( this->init < unit.init );
}

void CUnit::setName( CString str )
    {
        name = str;
    }
void CUnit::setInit( CString str )
    {
        init = str;
    }
void CUnit::setCHP( CString str )
    {
        chp = str;
    }
void CUnit::setRHP( CString str )
    {
        rhp = str;
    }
void CUnit::setCond( CString str )
    {
        condition = str;
    }
CString CUnit::getName() const
{
    return name;
}
CString CUnit::getInit() const
{
    return init;
}
CString CUnit::getCHP() const
{
    return chp;
}
CString CUnit::getRHP() const
{
    return rhp;
}
CString CUnit::getCond() const
{
    return condition;
}
```

I get the values from Editboxes successfuly but when I insert them in a `set<CUnit>` when I get the `CString` values back I only get the first letter. I tried with a vector but it's all the same. 
I fill the set like so:

```
vector<CUnit> units;
CUnit unit;
CEdit *edit;
CString str;
edit = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_NAME1));
edit->GetWindowText(str);
unit.setName(str);
edit = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_INIT1));
edit->GetWindowText(str);
unit.setInit(str);
edit = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_CHP1);
edit->GetWindowText(str);
unit.setCHP(str);
edit = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_RHP1));
edit->GetWindowText(str);
unit.setRHP(str);
edit = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_COND1+i));
edit->GetWindowText(str);
unit.setCond(str);
units.push_back(unit);
```

And I use this to check if everything is ok:

```
vector<CUnit>::iterator pos = units.begin();
str = *pos->getName();
SetDlgItemText(IDC_NAME2, str );
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code where you insert in the `set`?

Comment: Umm, so where's the `set<CUint>` stuff?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but in all the set functions, you should pass a const reference to CString, not a CString value. Thus, you avoid unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use as follows:

```
    str = *(pos->getName());
```

or

```
    str = (*pos).getName();
```

wish help you!